# Piping docker network ls to cut

Tags: docker, terminal, pipe, cut

I don't understand why

```
docker network ls | cut -f2
```

has no effect on the output of docker network ls. The output seems to be delimited by tabs. I would expect

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
5e2e0d7c6daf        bridge              bridge              local
5012d9100982        host                host                local
9574504d9579        test_default        bridge              local
0f7083dc1db7        php_fpm             bridge              local
```

to output

```
NAME             
bridge         
host    
test_default
php_fpm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default delimiter of `cut` is `tab`, and only one character allowed in cut, so it cannot meet your requirements, suggest to use `awk`:

```
docker network ls | awk -F'  +' '{print $2}'
```

Sample output:

> NAME
>
> bridge
>
> dashboard_default
>
> host
>
> none